# What does scaling of the upper bound of your algorithm's runtime tell you?

Tags: algorithm, performance, big-o, complexity-theory

Suppose the only thing you know is that your algorithm runs in `O(n^2)` time in the worst case. From this very fact you know that the upper bound looks like `Cn^2` for some `C > 0`. Thus you know how the upper bound of your algorithm scales, namely, if you double the input size the upper bound quadruples.

***Question***: What practical question can you answer if you know the way the upper bound scales? I just can't understand if this particular knowledge is helpful in some way.

Comment: You know how badly malicious or malformed data can harm your product's performance. You can also put an estimate on how much hardware you'll need to buy relative to how your userbase grows.

Comment: A very basic requirement for any program is that it can get the job done in the allotted amount of time.  Project disaster if it doesn't, it just is not usable.  https://www.hartmannsoftware.com/Blog/Obamacare_Website_Fail

Comment: You know that if someone else has an algorithm that can do the job with O(n) time complexity there is an input size above which their solution will outperform yours.

Comment: @trincot, why? If our algorithm runs in O(n^2) it actually could be in O(n) as well, since we didn't state anything about its Omega.

Comment: Indeed, I am assuming that O(n^2) is a tight bound for the worst case, like is common among coders.

Comment: You can also conclude that if someone else has an algorithm that is not O(n^2), even in its best case, that your algorithm will finish faster from a certain input size onwards than theirs.

Comment: @trincot, How is it possible? Suppose the second algorithm being in O(1). We can't actually know if my algorithm is going to outperform the second one.

Comment: No, I mean the second algorithm is not O(n^2), meaning it is not O(1), not O(logn), not O(n),  not O(nlogn), ...etc, but maybe O(n^3).

Comment: @trincot, Okay, the second algorithm could be both in O(n^3) and O(1). Then if my original algorithm is in Theta(n^2), then it never going to outperform the second one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237498/discussion-between-trincot-and-mathgeek).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know of an alternative algorithm that is *not* in O(²), then you may conclude that there is some minimum input size above which your algorithm will outperform the alternative algorithm.

This is because if () is not in O(²), then there do not exist  and *N* such that for every  >  we would have () < ². So you would also not find  and  such that () <  or () < log, ...etc. So () will not be O(1), O(), O(log), ... as it is not O(²).

Still, the input size for which your algorithm would outperform the alternative could be so astronomically great, that it would not be practical, and you would still prefer the alternative algorithm.

---

Please also realize that when coders speak of a time complexity for the worst case, they most often mean that this is a *tight* bound for the worst case. For example, if someone presents a sorting algorithm with a worst case time complexity of O(²), they mean that it does not have the worst case time complexity of O(log) that more efficient sorting algorithms have.

Answer (score 1):

If all you know about your algorithm's performance is that it's in O(n<sup>2</sup>), then in practical terms, what you know is this:

If the system has slowed to a crawl over time, and the database is 10 times the size that it used to be, then there's a good chance that the problem is your algorithm taking 100 times longer.

Comment: But that is just an assumption, since you can't expect your system to take 100 times longer if your input size gets 10 times bigger. There are two reasons for that. 1. Your algorithm's runtime could also be in **O(n)**. 2. From the fact f(n) ∈ O(n²) you can state **nothing** about scaling of the actual runtime of the algorithm.

Comment: 1) Not for sure, but if you don't *know* that your algorithm is in O(n) or O(n log n), then there's a good chance it's not.  2) from the fact that your algorithm is in O(n^2), experience of its runtime at one particular input size, and a general understanding of how algorithms for its particular problem tend to work, you can infer **a lot** about the way it scales in real life.  Programming is a practical pursuit. If you want to pretend that you don't know anything except what is given, switch to math :)

Comment: So, mathematically your answer is not correct, but practically that's exactly what it tells you? That's what you mean?

Comment: Yes.  Statements of upper complexity bounds are very useful in real life, even though you cannot formally derive from them anything useful about actual time taken.